# How to map csv file to pojo class in java

Tags: java, csv, mapping, pojo

I am using java maven plugin.I want to fetch employee.csv file records in pojo class.
this pojo class I am generating from employee.csv header and all fields of pojo class are String type.now I want to map employee.csv to generated pojo class.my requirement is I dont want to specify column names manually.because if I change csv file then again I have to chane my code so it should dynamically map with any file.    for instance

```
firstName,lastName,title,salary 
john,karter,manager,54372
```

I want to map this to pojo which I have already

```
public class Employee
{
  private String firstName;
  private String lastName;
  .
  .
  //getters and setters 
  //toString()
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Parse a delimited flat file to a POJO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13853357/how-to-parse-a-delimited-flat-file-to-a-pojo)

Comment: Please search over the internet/stackoverflow before posting a question

Comment: Actually  I gone through this and I googled it also but didn't  got the proper idea according to my requirement. my question is little bit different I will elaborate it. let me edit my question please

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[uniVocity-parsers](http://www.univocity.com/pages/parsers-tutorial) allows you to map your pojo easily.

```
class Employee {

    @Trim
    @LowerCase
    @Parsed
    private String firstName;

    @Parsed
    private String lastName;

    @NullString(nulls = { "?", "-" }) // if the value parsed in the quantity column is "?" or "-", it will be replaced by null.
    @Parsed(defaultNullRead = "0") // if a value resolves to null, it will be converted to the String "0".
    private Integer salary; // The attribute name will be matched against the column header in the file automatically.
    ...

}
```

To parse:

```
BeanListProcessor<Employee> rowProcessor = new BeanListProcessor<Employee>(Employee.class);

CsvParserSettings parserSettings = new CsvParserSettings();
parserSettings.setRowProcessor(rowProcessor);
parserSettings.setHeaderExtractionEnabled(true);

CsvParser parser = new CsvParser(parserSettings);

//And parse!
//this submits all rows parsed from the input to the BeanListProcessor
parser.parse(new FileReader(new File("/path/to/your.csv"))); 

List<Employee> beans = rowProcessor.getBeans();
```

Disclosure: I am the author of this library. It's open-source and free (Apache V2.0 license).

Answer (score -2):

you can use **openCSV** jar to read the data and then you can map the each column values with the class attributes.
Due to security reason, i can not share my code with you.

Comment: can you please elaborate more please.

Comment: when you will read the csv, as per my understanding it will be separated by "" so you can break it using it's class [click me](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/opencsv/CSVReader.html#CSVReader(java.io.Reader, char))